# Promise.all returns function

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, fetch

I would like use Async/Await with fetch API. So, i've 2 async function for `return result.json()`.

I add my 2 Promise in `Promise.all([])`, but the values returned is 'function()'.

My code :

```
  // Load external users
  const externalUsers = async () => {
    const result = await fetch(url);
    return result.json();
  };

  const localUsers = async () => {
    const result = await Users.allDocs({ include_docs: true });
    return result.rows;
  };

  Promise.all([externalUsers, localUsers]).then(values => {
    console.log(values); // return (2) [function, function]
  });
```

I don't understand why. Can you help me ?

Thank you community !

Comment: you want to execute the functions? `Promise.all([externalUsers(), localUsers()])`

Answer (score 9):

Run your functions in the `Promise.all`. So they will return Promises which will be **settled** and passed to the `then` function.

```
Promise.all([externalUsers(), localUsers()]).then(values => {
    console.log(values);
});
```

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to launch my functions with () :/. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 5):

You should `await` your `Promise.all`

```
const values = await Promise.all([...]);
const value1 = values[0];
...
```

The reason you are seeing functions, is because `Promise.all` returns a Promise that resolves to an array. So by `await`ing the `Promise.all`, you wait for them all to finish/resolve first.

Comment: [Promis.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) returns only a single Promise - not an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do,

```
const [externalUsersResult, localUsersResult] = await Promise.all([externalUsers, localUsers])
```